# I can't use AudioManager to switch input audio with android 11 and lower

Tags: android, react-native, audio, microphone, android-audiomanager

I have to try create function to change input audio in native module. When I test on samsung(android 13) and realme(android 12) it okay, but when I test on sharp(android 11) and some device have android version lower, it not work, my app always use built-in mic. How can I change input audio in android 11 or lower? thank you.

Code snippet:

```
@ReactMethod
    public void setAudioInput(String route) {
        audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        AudioDeviceInfo[] devices = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_INPUTS);

        if (route.contains("Bluetooth")) {
            audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
            audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);

            Log.d("setAudioRoute", "bluetooth");
        } else if (route.contains("Wired")) {
            for (AudioDeviceInfo device : devices) {
                if (device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET) {
                    audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
                    audioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
                    audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
                    break;
                }
            }

            Log.d("setAudioRoute", "wired headset");
        } else {
            audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
            audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
            audioManager.stopBluetoothSco();

            Log.d("setAudioRoute", "Built-in mic");
        }
    }
```